# Is it possible to keep subtracting BigDecimal on every button click?

Tags: java

is it possible to subtract BigDecimal on every button click?

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

BigDecimal amountPending;
BigDecimal myMoney = new BigDecimal("0.10");

JButton decrement;

public Test() {
    amountPending = new BigDecimal("5.5");

    setTitle("Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    decrement = new JButton("Decrement");
    decrement.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            BigDecimal x = amountPending.subtract(myMoney);
            System.out.println(x.doubleValue());
        }
    });

    add(decrement);

    setSize(100, 50);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();


   }
}
```

I am trying to decrement amount pending but then when I use double (non BigDecimal) the result will always be something like 1.0000000001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new variable `x` every time.

You should be updating the variable `amountPending` i.e.:

```
amountPending = amountPending.subtract(myMoney);
System.out.println(amountPending.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Oh wow it's this simple, how come I didn't realise this :')

thanks alot

Comment: Meta-answer: At a certain level, Java is really simple.  You just need to understand that simplicity.  Once you understand the simplicity, the solution to most problems are "obvious".  But getting to the stage where you really understand the simplicity, and the "obvious" solutions are really obvious (not just obvious in hindsight) takes ... experience and practice.